# Should more non-Muslims read this site?

Tags: discussion

Not a question, just a message to say what a great site this is.
I am not a Muslim, Jew or Christian, but if more non-Muslims read this we would have a far better understanding of your religion, and maybe all get along with each other far better.
I have learned more about the teachings of Islam in the last hour by reading this than in the rest of my life, and I have to say I agree with many of them.
Peace and goodwill to you all, and once again, well done everyone concerned with this.

Comment: Hi Shaun, make sure you read the [about] page too, and have a look at the [help] - these site's don't operate like traditional forums at all. (And I'm pretty sure a lot of non-Muslims read this site.)