# Should we (slowly) flag the "bot friendly site" comments as "no longer needed"?

Tags: support, comments, flagging

Years ago, there was this post [Welcome to the bot friendly site](https://islam.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1540/17163) accompanied by a whole bunch of comments, such as:

> Hello and [Welcome to the bot friendly site](http://meta.islam.stackexchange.com/questions/1540/welcome-to-the-bot-friendly-site). Please learn [how to answer](http://islam.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer) in order to make it a damn cool answer. Plz take some time for that.
> <sub>[[link](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/24597/why-was-prophet-lot-pbh-told-not-to-look-back#comment43020_24632)]</sub>
>
> Hello and [Welcome to the bot friendly site](http://meta.islam.stackexchange.com/questions/1540/welcome-to-the-bot-friendly-site).
> <sub>[[link](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/24480/will-there-be-another-world-after-this#comment42617_24480)]</sub>
>
> Hello and [Welcome to the bot friendly site](http://meta.islam.stackexchange.com/questions/1540/welcome-to-the-bot-friendly-site) plz make sure you learn the basics of this site from the [Help Center](http://islam.stackexchange.com/help) and also learn [How to ask](http://islam.stackexchange.com/help/asking) and [How to answer](http://islam.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer) before posting. Also plz try to edit your 'title' and easily searchable :)
> <sub>[[link](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/24004/why-the-good-deeds-of-muslims-are-rewarded-more-than-a-person-belonging-to-the-u#comment41726_24004)]</sub>

I see multiple problems with this:

1. At the time, [Bleeding Fingers](https://islam.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1542/17163) made the obvious observation that this is *not a bot friendly site*, along with highlighting numerous inaccuracies with the meta post.
2. I doubt someone is going to think "I'm going to find instructions on how to use the site by clicking that link".  They're going to think it's about bots.
3. These comments are informal, writing e.g. "damn cool answer", and "Plz".  (And it should use a compound adjective "bot-friendly site".)
4. Nowadays, they're old comments.
5. As Andrew T. said in the comments, it could be misinterpreted as implying the OP was behaving like a bot.

**Question**: Should I flag the "bot friendly site" comments as "no longer needed"?

Searching [`site:islam.stackexchange.com bot friendly site`](http://cn.bing.com/search?q=site%3Aislam.stackexchange.com%20bot%20friendly%20site), makes it look like there's hundreds of these.  Thus, if they should be flagged, it should probably be done over time.

Some of them have some additional content, which could be considered useful.  So perhaps something different might need to be done in this case.

Comment: The comment doesn't really look like welcoming the user at all... IMHO, saying "welcome to the bot friendly site" implied that the poster (not the commenter) was a bot, which is kind of offensive.

Comment: @AndrewT. Fair point; I'll add it to the list.

Comment: Looks like all these comments are gone.